# Passing value from JSP scriptlet to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I want  to display table contents and edit the the specific row obtained based on unique id fetched by clicking submit button for respective row.

Below code is for listing all the records from table with edit button on every row:

```
<TABLE align="Center" border="1px" width="80%">
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <%List data=(List) request.getAttribute("UserData");
    for(itr=data.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
    {%>
        <tr>
            <% String s= (String) itr.next(); %> <!-- Stores the value (uniquie id) in the String s -->
            <td><%=s %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
            <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
```

When I click the edit button I want to get the value from first column and first row which contains unique id. 
The code fetching the value from String "s" is given below:

```
<form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post"  onsubmit=<%=s %>>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
</form>
```

Now I want to pass this value stored in String s to my servlet "EditRecord" but somehow the value is not getting passed.

The code for servlet is given below:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet res = null;
    String id   ;
    String query;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;


//  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        id=request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
        conn=dbconn.setConnection();
        System.out.println(conn);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(stmt);
        query="select * from user_details where User_id="+id;
        res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
        System.out.println(res);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }finally{
        request.setAttribute("EditData",res );
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/editdata.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        out.close();
    }


    }
```

}

Could anyone tell me where I am making the mistake..Please guide me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onSubmit` event is invoked when the submit button is clicked, but it doesn't send any data to the server.

In your case I suggest you to add a **hidden input** to the **form**, so it will be sent to the server when submit button is clicked. Check the code below:

```
<form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
  <td><input type="hidden" id="id" value="<%=s %>"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
</form>
```